# Density of $e^{inx}$ on $L^1([-\pi,\pi))$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I have been reading and it came to my notice that if we work with the $L^1(\mathbb{T})=L^1([-\pi,\pi))$. The author says that we can add the point and use Stone Weiertrass theroem to see that $\operatorname{span}\{e^{inx}\}$ is dense.
I try to prove it directly i.e. $\operatorname{span}\{e^{inx}\}$ is dense on $L^1([-\pi,\pi))$.

First I prove that $C([-\pi,\pi))\subset L^1([-\pi,\pi))$ is dense, using the fact that simple functions are dense. The continuous and integrable functions is what I mean when I write $C[-\pi,\pi))\subset L^1([-\pi,\pi))$

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The set of continuous functions in $\mathbb{T}$ is sense in $L_1(\mathbb{T})$. The $\operatorname{span}\{f_n(z)=z^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+,\} $ is dense in $C(\mathbb{T})$ by the (complex version) of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. For all practical reason, one can identify functions in $L_1([-\pi,\pi)$ with periodic functions (period $2\pi$) and so $L_1(\mathbb{T})$ and $L_1([-\pi,\pi))$ are in a way the same thing.

Comment: The Stone Weirstrass complex version states that if $A$ is a of complex continuous functions continuous on a compact se $K$,  separating points, and $f\in A$ iff $\overline{f}\in A$, then the space of polynomials in $A$ (linear combinations of finite product os elements in $A$)  is dense in $C(K;\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: So if I undersand correctly  $f\in L^1([-\pi,\pi))$ is $2\pi$ periodic over $\mathbb{R}$ and hence I can identify it with a function on $L^1(\mathbb{T})$

Comment: No, $C([-\pi,\pi))$ is **not** a subset of $L^1([-\pi,\pi))$. (for example, $f(t)=1/(t-\pi)$.

Comment: What I meant was the the continuous and integrable functions are dense.

Comment: @juaaan: Functions defined on $[-\pi,\pi)$ can be extended as $2\pi$-periodic functions on the whole real line and so, they can be consider as functions on $\mathbb{T}$. It is then more convenient to work on $\mathbb{T}$ which is compact and so any $C(\mathbb{R})$ can be approximated by trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: @juaaan: as David C. Ulrich mentioned, $C([-\pi,\pi)]$ is not a subspace of $L_1([-\pi,\pi)$. Through identifying $2\pi$-periodic functions with functions on $\mathbb{T}$ we have $C(\mathbb{T})\subset L_(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I understand that, but in the context that I was more interested I was considering only integrable continuous function, and I ended up abusing the notation.

Comment: @juaaan: The author is basically using the one-point compactification of $[-\pi,pi)$, which happenes to be $\mathbb{T}$, so that one can take advantage of classical results about density on  continuous functions on compact sets.